# mysql: update if exists else insert and in both case return the id

Tags: mysql, sql

I know this has been asked a lot of times and I have checked most of the questions but havent found an answer that suits my problem.

I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (                                   
      `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                  
      `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                           
      `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                                            
      `Added_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,                                             
      PRIMARY KEY (`Id`,`Email`)                             
    )
```

I will be inserting records in this table from the screen wherein I will ask the users for the `Name` and `EmailId` of their friends.

What I want to do is simply check the Email id, if the same email id exists in my Users table, then update the `name` entered. Else insert a new record. And in both the cases I want the userId of the record that has been inserted or updated.

Sounds simple!

But I tried `Replace`, `Insert.. on duplicate key update`, `insert where not exists` but none of them have worked for me. This is what I have tried so far:

**REPLACE**

```
REPLACE INTO Users SET email = 'a@d.c';
```

But this will keep on inserting new record everytime as the `name` is not checked. Not sure if I am using it correctly.

**INSERT.. ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE**

```
insert into Users (id, Name, Email, Added_date) values (null, 'ABCD', 'adb@di.co',current_date) on duplicate key update Name='XYZ';
```

This wont work since the primary key of the table is a composition of (id and emailid) and since the ID is auto-incremental, it will insert a new record everytime.

I know I can write an `update` query to check if there is any record with a particular email_id, if yes then it will get updated else I will `insert` a new record. And I can get the new incremented ID using `$userId = mysql_insert_id();`. But how can I get the ID in case of the update query?

I believe there has to be a better way of doing this thing than writing update and insert queries separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary key should be set on Users.Id only, for the Email just make it unique

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (                                   
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,                  
  `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                           
  `Email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,                                            
  `Added_Date` date DEFAULT NULL,                                             
  PRIMARY KEY (Id),
  UNIQUE KEY Email (Email)                            
)
```

And your query will be like that, note that you can you VALUES() function to retrieve the new value.

```
Insert into Users (Id, Name, Email, Added_date) 
values (null, 'ABCDe','adb@di.co',current_date) 
on duplicate key update Name=VALUES(Name);
```

Comment: thanks.. that worked. It returns the id of the updated record as well and hence solved my other problem too!

Answer (score 0):

I did not read your question to the end, but now I can say that the table schema is not correct. Primary key must be defined as PRIMARY KEY (`Id`), email must be defined as Email varchar(50) UNIQUE

Comment: You can put your answer in comment section of Question as it does not contain real answer...